# How to add a "noze" to an axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to add an arbitrary length to an axis, but I don't know how.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  NbGrad/.store in=\NbGrad,
  Noze/.store in=\Noze,
  Noze=.5cm,
   }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    >=stealth,x=6cm,font=\footnotesize,NbGrad=6]

\draw [->] (0,0)--(1+\Noze,0)  ;

\foreach \x in {0,1,...,\NbGrad} {%
    \coordinate (\x) at (\x/\NbGrad,0) ;
    \draw [very thin] (\x/\NbGrad,+2pt)--(\x/\NbGrad,-2pt) ;

    \pgfmathsetmacro\result{2 + \x / 10}
    \node[above=1pt,text depth=1.5pt]  at (\x)%
        {\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=1,fixed,use comma]{\result}};

    } ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I found this :  `\draw [->] (0,0)--(1,0)-- ++(\Noze,0)  ;`
that works.

Comment: Well, Paulo Cereda made an effort here, but it's probably not what you look for ;) http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13789779#13789779

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for ! It became my online image. How to thank him ? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `calc` library:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  NbGrad/.store in=\NbGrad,
  Noze/.store in=\Noze,
  Noze=2.5cm,
   }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    >=stealth,x=6cm,font=\footnotesize,NbGrad=6]

\draw [->] (0,0)--($(1,0) +(\Noze,0)$)  ;

\foreach \x in {0,1,...,\NbGrad} {%
    \coordinate (\x) at (\x/\NbGrad,0) ;
    \draw [very thin] (\x/\NbGrad,+2pt)--(\x/\NbGrad,-2pt) ;

    \pgfmathsetmacro\result{2 + \x / 10}
    \node[above=1pt,text depth=1.5pt]  at (\x)%
        {\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=1,fixed,use comma]{\result}};

    } ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]